# SQL SUM() and ANGULAR.JS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I know how to connect, display, remove, add data from my database and display all of it on my website. Everthing works correctly. I see my results on my website and in my database.  I do this with AngularJS, AJAX and PHP but my problem is I don't know how to dispaly MYSQL SUM() one of my column. For example this is my table in mysql and I would like to dispaly the total sum of the money column.

```
id    money

1     23

2     345

3     111
```

This is what I got:

**index.html:**

..................

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Money</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ wcdrates.sumMoney }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

.................

I don't know If I should leave ng-repeat as it is or use something different instead. Anyway ng-repeat dosent'work. It shows me all results from money column not the total SUM.
............

**controller.js**

.....................

```
$http.post('./php/showMoney.php')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.wcdrates = data;
  })
  .error(function(err) {
    $log.error(err);
  })
```

....................

**connectDatabase.php**

```
<?php
define("__HOST__", "127.0.0.1");
define("__USER__", "root");
define("__PASS__", "");
define("__BASE__", "davbaza");

class DB {
    private $con = false;
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->con = new mysqli(__HOST__, __USER__, __PASS__, __BASE__);

        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die("DB connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    public function qryPop() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wcdrates` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
        $qry = $this->con->query($sql);
        if($qry->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $qry->fetch_object()) {
                $this->data[] = $row;
            }
        } else {
            $this->data[] = null;
        }
        $this->con->close();
    }



    public function qryFire($sql=null) {
        if($sql == null) {
            $this->qryPop();
        } else {
            $this->con->query($sql);
            $this->qryPop();    
        }
        //$this->con->close();
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

?>

**showMoney.php**

```
<?php 

include('connectDatabase.php');

$db = new DB();

$sql = "SELECT SUM(money) as sumMoney FROM wcdrates";

$data = $db->qryFire();

echo json_encode($data);
```

mysql

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wcdrates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I have no idea what I should change to get what I want.

Comment: in you sql use `SUM(money) as sumMoney` then you can access it the controller too with name of `sumMoney`

Comment: " {{wcdrates.sumMoney}} 
     
 
it dosen't work, I did as you said but still nothing, any ideas?

Comment: con you `console.log(data)` after `success`? If you got share with me!

Comment: this is what I got: Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]

Comment: run this on `angular.forEach(data,function(d){ console.log(d) })` and see give me the output!

Comment: Object { id: "1", money: "23" }
Object { id: "2", money: "345" }
Object { id: "3", money: "111" }      this is what I got

Answer (score 2):

change the `qryPop` in your code , to following code .

```
 $sql = "SELECT id,money , SUM(money) as sumMoney FROM `wcdrates` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
```

Hope you will get the answer